# A very basic question about notations of function spaces that makes me confused

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

Assume we have a function space $V$ such that for any function $f$ in $V$ the mapping is $f: X \to R$, and a subdomain $Y \subset X$ for the restriction of the function, say, $f|_Y: Y \to R$ in the restricted function space $V|_Y$. Then, can we say $V \subset V|_Y$ or $V|_Y \subset V$?

Comment: Neither inclusion is actually true unless $Y=X$: a function with domain $X$ is not a function with domain $Y$, so $V\nsubseteqq V|_Y$, and a function with domain $Y$ is not a function with domain $X$, so $V|_Y\nsubseteqq V$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! If we define $f: X \to R$ as a canonical extension of $f|_Y: Y \to R$ where $Y \subset X$, then do we have the inclusion?

Comment: You don’t have an inclusion, but you do have a natural embedding.